# Can an Android app have both normal screens and game screens?

Tags: android, game-development

I want to make a "normal" Android app. But I want to put gane elements in it, like a screen where the user will be able to see his character and move it around, jump some plataforms, etc.

I am no game dev, but I wanted to know if this is possible, to mix game screens and normal screens in an Android app.

I am using Jetpack Compose to develop my app. How are game screens made? With xml?

Comment: You can mix apple and patato screens as much as you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an Android app can certainly have both normal screens and game screens. Android applications are not limited to a specific type of content or functionality. Developers have the flexibility to create diverse experiences within a single app, including traditional user interfaces for regular interactions and specialized game screens for gaming elements. This allows for a wide range of applications, from utility apps with standard interfaces to those that incorporate interactive and immersive game-like features.